# __report_bad_irq not getting hit

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, devices, interrupt, irq

I am stucked in one issue, in which i am getting *__report_bad_irq* callstack inconsistently.

AFAIK, whenever we have 100000 unhandled interrupts this stack kicks in.

Output from cat /proc/irq/128/spurious at a specified time

count 99343

unhandled 98981

last_unhandled 7983944 ms

--After few minutes--

count 212

unhandled 212

last_unhandled 7985960 ms

count gives the total number of times the IRQ fired, modulo 100,000 but,
Why this particular irq is not getting disabled when its count is reaching 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

We hit the bad_irq stack when if 99,900 of the previous 100,000 interrupts have not been handled.
The other 100-of-100,000 interrupts may have been a correctly functioning device sharing an IRQ with the failing one.
So it will be a matter of chance that 99,900 are unhandled for disabling the irq,
the irq will not get disabled even if total unahandled is 99,000 and total count reaches 100,000.